# SASS compiled to 1 css rule with multiple selectors?

Tags: compass-sass

Im using SASS. I need to have class-1 and class-2 at different places in my stylesheet, like so:

```
.class-1 {
  // something
}

.class-A {
  // something
}
.class-2 {
 // something  
}
```

How can I write SASS that compiles like this:

```
.class-1,
.class-2 {
 color: red;
}
```

Not like this:

```
.class-1 {
 color: red;
}
.class-2 {
 color: red;
}
```

Comment: Why not just write it as you have your second block in Sass? It will compile just like that then.

Comment: I have all the styles for one page together in my file, and the styles for another page in a different place in the file. I want to keep my file organised in this way so class-1 and class-2 are not close to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @extend feature does this, but it seems to have a lot of gotchas so Im not sure ill use it right away.